# But when will $i^x=2$?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, complex-numbers, logarithms

So I was looking through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math equations that I might be able to solve when I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a14ym_o0EfE) video by Blackpenredpen asking if $i^x$ will ever equal $2$, which I thought that I might be able to find a solution for. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$i^x=2$$$$\implies x\ln(i)=\ln(2)$$$$\implies x=\dfrac{\ln(2)}{\ln(i)}$$Which now we need to simplify $\ln(i)$. Here's how we do so: Using Euler's Identity$$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$Since we know that$$-1=\cos(\pi+2\pi k)+i\sin(\pi+2\pi k)=e^{i\pi+2i\pi k}$$since $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are both periodic with period $2\pi$ (if I remember correctly),$$\implies i=\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{e^{i\pi+2i\pi k}}=e^{\frac{i\pi}2+i\pi k}$$$$\implies x=\dfrac{\ln(2)}{\ln(i)}$$$$=\dfrac{\ln(2)}{\left(\dfrac{i\pi}2+i\pi k\right)}$$$$\implies\dfrac{\ln(2)}{\left(\dfrac{i\pi+2i\pi k}2\right)}$$$$=\dfrac{2\ln(2)}{i\pi+2i\pi k},k\in\mathbb{Z}$$Which we can prove that that is the answer like this:$$i^x=2$$$$i^\frac{2\ln(2)}{i\pi+2i\pi k}=2$$$$\implies\dfrac{2\ln(2)\ln(i)}{i\pi+2i\pi k}=\ln(2)$$$$\implies\dfrac{2\ln(i)}{i\pi+2i\pi k}=1$$$$2\ln(i)=i\pi+2i\pi k$$$$i^2=-1=e^{i\pi+2i\pi k}$$$$\therefore i^\frac{2\ln(2)}{i\pi+2i\pi k}\overset\checkmark=2$$$$\therefore\text{ for any }i^x=z$$$$z=\dfrac{2\ln(z)}{i\pi+2i\pi k},k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

---

## My question

---

---

Is the solution that I have achieved correct, or what could I do to achieve the correct solution or attain it more easily?

---

### Mistakes I might have made

---

---

1. Remembering Euler's Identity
2. Remembering the period of both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$
3. My assumption for solving any $i^x=z$
4. Complex logarithms :\

---

---

#### To clarify

---

1. The final result should probably be written as $$x=\dfrac{-2i\ln(2)}{\pi+2\pi k}$$meaning that for any $$i^x=z$$$$x=\dfrac{-2i\ln(z)}{\pi+2\pi k}$$

Comment: Actually I might need to edit something in for clarification: the final writing of the result should be written as $x=\dfrac{-2i\ln(2)}{\pi+2\pi k}$ which I will edit in probably now

Comment: $\ln i=\frac{i\pi}{2}+\color{blue}{2}i\pi k$. You went wrong from there.

Comment: If you do use a complex logarithm, $i^x=2\implies x\ln(i)=\ln(2)+2\pi i n\implies x=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(i)}+\frac{2\pi i n}{\ln(i)},\ln(i)=\frac{\pi i }2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would express it this way. The equation
$$i^z = 2$$
is equivalent to
$$e^{iz\pi/2} = 2.$$
If $z = x + iy$ ($x,y\in \mathbb R$), then we get
$$e^{-y\pi/2}\cdot e^{ix\pi/2}=2,$$
which requires
$$e^{-y\pi/2} = 2 \ \ \land \ \frac{x\pi}2 = 2k\pi,$$
with $k \in \mathbb Z.$
So in conclusion we have
$$ z_k = 4k - i\cdot \frac{2\log 2}{\pi}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $\frac{2 \log 2}{\pi i}$ is among the solutions.  The elements of the solution set are not all pure imaginary, rather

$$x \in \left\{ -\frac{2 \log 2}{\pi}i +4 k \right\}, \quad \text{where } k \in \mathbb{Z} $$